# TextView aligned horizontally with EditText and the EditText aligned on the right of parent

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Apologize for the confusing wordings.

Here's a LinearLayout:

```
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Note:" />

       <EditText

           android:hint="Add Note"
           android:gravity="right"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

This is the actual output:

[image]

And this is the expected output:

[image]

How to set the EditText aligned on the right of the LinearLayout while still horizontally aligned with the TextView? And I also want the **layout_width** of the EditText to be wrap_content, so it doesn't occupy the rest of the LinearLayout

Answer (score 0):

So you just want give space between edittext and textview, if yes, give another linearlayout between edditext and textview like this

```
   <TextView
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Note:" />

   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:weightSum="1"/>

   <EditText

       android:hint="Add Note"
       android:gravity="right"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Let me know if i wrong assume your question

Answer (score 0):

You can add any sort of view in between them with a `layout_weight` of 1 and a width of `0dp`, then set the `layout_weight` to 0 on the other views so the middle one stretches to fill the remaining space, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Note:" 
        android:layout_weight="0"/>
    
    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        />

    <EditText
        android:hint="Add Note"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Giving you this layout

[image: layout]

Alternately, you can use a ConstraintLayout to avoid having to add the extra view, like this:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Note:"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/editText"/>
    
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:hint="Add Note"
        android:gravity="right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is especially helpful if you have a lot of layouts like this on a screen, you can do this with a single ConstraintLayout instead of multiple nested LinearLayouts.

Answer (score 0):

An easier way would be to use ConstraintLayout for this. If you haven't used ConstraintLayout before, do give it a try. Read this to know more - https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/08/understanding-performance-benefits-of.html

For the code part -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:text="Note:"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:hint="Add Note"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here's how it looks -
PS - I removed the underline by adding the background as null.

[image]